# Print With PyWin32: Where to Put File Name?

Tags: python, file, printing, pywin32, network-printers

I can successfully print a test page through a network printer using PyWin32 and change the tray using the following code:

```
 device_name = "Printer Name"
 handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(device_name)

 properties = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
 devmode = properties['pDevMode']

 devmode.DefaultSource = 260
 devmode.Fields = devmode.Fields | DM_DEFAULT_SOURCE

 win32print.DocumentProperties(None, handle, device_name, devmode, devmode, 
 DM_IN_BUFFER | DM_OUT_BUFFER)

 hdc = win32gui.CreateDC('', device_name, devmode)
 win32print.StartDoc(hdc, ('Test', None, None, 0))
 win32print.StartPage(hdc)

 win32print.EndPage(hdc)
 win32print.EndDoc(hdc)
```

My question is, if I want to print a specific file, where do I put the file name?

Answer (score 0):

The file name is to be supplied in `StartDoc`, where the second parameter is tuple for [`DOCINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-_docinfow)

For example, this will print to a PDF printer with file name 'test.pdf':

```
hdc = win32gui.CreateDC('', device_name, devmode)
win32print.StartDoc(hdc, ('Test', 'test.pdf', None, 0))
win32print.StartPage(hdc)
```

> [`win32print.StartDoc`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32print__StartDoc_meth.html)
>
> `int = StartDoc(hdc, docinfo )`
>
> Starts spooling a print job on a printer device context
>
> Parameters
>
> `hdc : PyHANDLE`
>   Printer device context handle as returned by `win32gui::CreateDC`
>
> `docinfo : tuple`
>   `DOCINFO` tuple specifying print job parameters

Comment: This generates a file with the name specified, but I am trying to send an existing file to the printer?

Comment: You might want to delete this answer as it does **not** answer the question but instead generates a file with the specified name, as written in the first comment.

Comment: @MrUpsidown There is no API for printing any random file, if that's your question. For example if you have a zip file, then Windows has no idea how to print it. If the file has a print handler in registry then you can ask the OS to print it. The APIs posted in the question is for printing to a file, where your application decides what to print.

Comment: Agreed. Still your answer doesn't provide an answer to the question: *My question is, if I want to print a specific file, where do I put the file name?*

Comment: It's not asking how to print *to* a file. It's asking how to print a specific file. An existing file. And I am not asking another question. Back to my first comment.